# on click function is getting triggered on load

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery click function but that function is getting called on the load of the page

```
jQuery("[tm-gb]").on("click change", function(event) {

}
```

Is there any way that this function is not called on page load?

Comment: The problem is not really clear here because it could depend on your structure and other JS codes. Could you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: thats because something on your page is triggering  `change` event on your  element (selector `[tm-gb]`) by updating its value.

Comment: A click event is of course not triggered when loading a page. Same case for the `change` event, the element is not changing on the page when loading (or the javascript is just too late with initializing.

Comment: The problem is not with change as i removed change from the function there is no difference. but when i remove click from the function this function is working fine

Answer (score -1):

If you want call on page load you can use `window.load` function :

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    alert("window load occurred!");
});
```

You can use load event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").load(function(){
        alert("Image loaded.");
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't related to OP's question whatsoever!